# How to decode anchor zero copy account with idl?

Tags: anchor, solana-program, anchor-client, anchor-program-idl

The zero copy version of the following struct adds 4 bytes of padding between arg_1 and arg_2. This makes the idl not able to decode the struct correctly as arg_2 is being decoded based on the 4 bytes of padding and its own first 4 bytes.

```
#[account(zero_copy)]
#[derive(Default)]
pub struct MyStruct  {
    pub version: u8,
    pub bump: u8,
    pub active: bool,
    pub authority: Pubkey,
    pub arg_1: u8,
    pub arg_2: u64,
}
```

How do I fix this?

Comment: Try and see: (1) https://stackoverflow.com/a/72750493/5678403 (2) https://github.com/yourarj/solana-anchor-zero-copy/blob/master/programs/solana-anchor-zero-copy/src/lib.rs . Might help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Anchor zero copy doesn't follow the rules of how `Pod` (the backing trait from bytemuck) is supposed to be implemented (violates the unsafe constraints). To fix it you need to add `#[repr(packed)]` to get rid of the padding (will mis-align reference but follow the clippy warnings to be fine) and not use and non-Pod types in the struct.