# How to correctly read data from a Zero Copy account

Tags: anchor, account, account-data

I'm having trouble reading data in the client from a program with a zero copy account. I've defined the account as follows:

```
#[account(zero_copy)]
#[repr(packed)]
pub struct EventQueue {
    header: EventQueueHeader,
    head: u64,
    buf: [Event; 100], // Used zero_copy to expand eventsQ size
}
```

The data appears to be shifted via padding and is appearing incorrect in the client when fetched as follows (note without zero copy, data is correctly fetched).

```
const eventQ = await program.account.eventQueue.fetch(eventQPda);
console.log(eventQ);
```

I've tried using `#[repr(packed)]` as per this question[https://solana.stackexchange.com/questions/2861/how-to-decode-anchor-zero-copy-account-with-idl],  but the output is still wrong.

The on-chain values are being set and read correctly, and the program is able to utilise values stored in the EventQueue Account. Any thoughts on the best way to do this?

Edit:

Some additional info -
EventQueue has an alignment of 0x10, based on Event which also has an alignment of 0x10. EventQueueHeader has an alignment of 0x8.

As suggested by one of the answers, I attempted to update the eventQueue to manually align with the  most-significant alignment as follows:
#[account(zero_copy)]
#[repr(C)]
pub struct EventQueue {

```
header: EventQueueHeader,
pub _reserved0: [u8; 8],

head: u64,
pub _reserved1: [u8; 8],
buf: [Event; 100], // Used zero_copy to expand eventsQ size
```

}`
However, the misalignment persists. Any further suggestions? Also, could it be that I need to manually align the Event struct as well?

Comment: Have you tried #[repr(C)]? It's generally easier to handle padding/alignment issues with C.

Comment: Whats in the EventQueueHeader the only things that are serialized differently with different repr types are enums and option types afaik.

Answer (score 3):

tl;dr use repr(C) and manually align the struct to the most-significant alignment.

The problem is likely a struct alignment issue, which commonly manifests as `fetch` failing due to bad serialization or returning nonsense.

Consider this struct:

```
// Actual Size = 2 + 6 + 18_724 * 56 + 24 = 1_048_576
#[account(zero_copy)]
#[repr(C)]
pub struct AuditLog {
    pub next_slot: u16,
    pub in_order: bool,
    pub _reserved0: [u8; 5],
    pub log: [AuditEntry; 18_724],
    pub _reserved1: [u8; 24],
}

// Size 56 = 32 + 8 + 8 + 8
#[derive(AnchorSerialize, AnchorDeserialize, Clone, Copy)]
#[repr(C)]
pub struct AuditEntry {
    pub user: Pubkey,
    pub timestamp: i64,
    pub total_cost: u64,
    pub total_proceeds: u64,
}
```

Note that `AuditEntry` is aligned to 0x8 bytes (if you have Rust Analyzer in VS Code, hover over a struct to see its alignment). There's a 32-byte field (a multiple of 8), then three 8-byte values.

`AuditLog` is also aligned to 8 bytes, because `AuditEntry` is, and the highest alignment is used. If we didn't have `_reserved0`, it would fail to deserialize correctly, because `next_slot` is 2 bytes, then `in_order` is 1, we must manually reach the next 8-byte multiple, hence the use of the `_reserved0` buffer that is 5 bytes large. The next field, `log`, aligns to 8 bytes, and so does the `_reserved1` buffer at the end, so those are fine.

If we removed the `AuditEntry` array from `AuditLog` so it looked like this:

```
#[account(zero_copy)]
#[repr(C)]
pub struct AuditLogAlt {
    pub next_slot: u16,
    pub in_order: bool,
    pub _reserved0: [u8; 5],
    pub _reserved1: [u8; 24],
}
```

now it aligns to 0x2 bytes (the u16 dictates the alignment here). Here we could make `_reserved0` a size 1 array, and it would still align correctly. If `next_slot` was u32, it would align to 0x4 bytes, or 0x8 if it was u64, and paradoxically u128 is 0x8 too (thanks compiler magic).

Now for your example, it depends on what the highest alignment is, which will probably come from `EventQueueHeader` or `Event`. You likely need to add padding between `header` and `head` and/or between `head` and `buf` to meet that alignment. For example, if `EventQueueHeader` aligns 16, and `Event` aligns 8, you would make it:

```
#[account(zero_copy)]
#[repr(C)]
pub struct EventQueue {
    header: EventQueueHeader,
    head: u64,
    pub _reserved0: [u8; 8],
    buf: [Event; 100], // Used zero_copy to expand eventsQ size
}
```

Or if `Event` and `EventQueueHeader` and both aligned to 0x4 bytes:

```
#[account(zero_copy)]
#[repr(C)]
pub struct EventQueue {
    header: EventQueueHeader,
    pub _reserved0: [u8; 4],
    head: u64,
    buf: [Event; 100], // Used zero_copy to expand eventsQ size
}
```

And so forth...

Comment: If you used `#[repr(C)]`, why do you need the fields `_reserved0` and `_reserved1`? You don't need these fields (and manual alignments) because there will be padding anyway because you used `#[repr(C)]`.  If you had used `#[repr(packed)]`, then what you did makes sense, because `packed` would remove the padding between members and some members such as `AuditEntry` would start at non-aligned memory!

Comment: If you use `[repr(C)]` you don't get any automatic padding added, so you must manually align your values to the highest alignment of the struct. The reason is that the Anchor `zero_copy` implementation DOES add padding, and in my experience it doesn't always add the same padding as `#[repr(packed)]`, because it uses a custom implementation with `[repr(C)]` (https://book.anchor-lang.com/anchor_references/space.html) that isn't exactly what you would expect from a POD type.

Comment: _"The reason is that the Anchor zero_copy implementation DOES add padding"_. What is the basis of this claim? Can you show me the proof? Also, do you know what `#[repr(C)]` actually is? You're claiming too much without even verifying your assumptions.

Comment: Or, can you tell me the difference between `#[repr(C)]` and `#[repr(packed)]`?

Comment: _"in my experience it doesn't always add the same padding as `#[repr(packed)]`"_. Do you even understand what you're saying here? Do you even understand what `#[repr(packed)]` does? It does NOT add any padding. Its name itself screams this fact. It's aptly named PACKED means no padding, no space between members.

Comment: ` #[repr(packed)]` = no padding, Anchor's `zero_copy` implementation DOES add padding. `zero_copy` implements bytemuck POD, see the safety guide here: https://docs.rs/bytemuck/latest/bytemuck/trait.Pod.html#safety, which plainly states: "The type needs to be `repr(C)` or `repr(transparent)`. In the case of `repr(C)`, the `packed` and `align` repr modifiers can be used as long as all other rules end up being followed." That means you can use packed, if everything already aligns.

Comment: You should also read the warning for `packed`: (https://doc.rust-lang.org/nomicon/other-reprs.html), it is very likely to cause alignment issues that the compiler can't fix and "Unless you have extreme requirements, this should not be used." Manually aligning fields with `repr(c)` is more reliable, e.g. you know the field aligns 8, so declare padding that aligns 1 up to the next byte multiple of 8. As above, `log` needs to align 8 and so `_reserved0` adds 5 one-aligned bytes to reach the next multiple of 8.

Answer (score 2):

To be honest, I'm surprised that `#[repr(packed)]` isn't working, since that's exactly what you're looking to do. You have a couple of options:

- update your client-side deserialization -- when you use zero-copy, there may still be padding introduced between fields and instances in the array. Normally, `#[repr(packed)]` should take care of that, but it can be finnicky. So just update the client to take padding into account.
- remove all padding in your type to be sure that everything aligns to `1`. For example, `u64` aligns to `8`, so if `EventQueueHeader` aligns to something smaller, then there will be padding between the two fields. You can get around this by using `Pod`-safe types, like `PodU64` which is just a byte array under the hood. Here's an example doing that for `u32` https://github.com/solana-labs/solana-program-library/blob/db5e69edb14e626e294f9f32e2526757b8605774/libraries/type-length-value/src/pod.rs#L48. The same applies to `Event`, since there can also be padding between array instances.

I believe Anchor uses `bytemuck` under the hood, and you can read more about its `Pod` types at https://docs.rs/bytemuck/latest/bytemuck/trait.Pod.html